# How can I print different bands depending on the value of a Field in a DataSet using FastReport?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a product's dataset and I want to have distinct bands for each type of product, something like, if the product is a fruit, print it's weight, if the product is a car print its color and so on.

And I want to let my users customize it, so each band for each type o product will be perfect.

My DataSet have all fields from all type of products and I have a field which determines the product type of the actual record.

Is there some easy to way to do it?

Comment: Did u do this ?if so how can  you help me?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688024/how-to-change-the-fastreport-layout-in-xe7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FastReports allows you to intercept the program's default report construction process with events at several useful places. If you have, for example a master band, in its OnBeforePrint event, you can put code that checks out the type of product and then a case statement could set the visible property to true only on detail bands that are the right kind of property.

I have found the news group at [news://newsgroups.fast-report.com/fast-reports.public.fastreport.4](http://news://newsgroups.fast-report.com/fast-reports.public.fastreport.4) to be an incredible source of help and encouragement.  I am sure you can find a much better answer to your question there.