# How to change the fastreport layout in xe7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, fastreport

I want to change the Layout or band in fast report depending upon the dataset value ,how can be this done in fastreport 5.0 AND  I am using delphiXE7
If it's a car ticket I want to print car and if its bike I want to print the bike details ,My data set have values of all orders in which  some orders may have car and bike tickets so , When I generate the report (report is the ticket for my application) based on the data set value if its car I want to show car images and if its bike different images of bike based on data set values and different style how can this be done?

OR This can be done  by changing the .fr3 file?

```
  with  frxCODOrdersDBDataset.DataSet do
    begin
       First;
    while not Eof do
    begin     
      if FieldByName('draw_name').AsString='CAR_TICKET' then
       begin
   frxCODOrdersReport.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\WebTicketPdf\CarTicketPdf.fr3');
   frxCODOrdersReport.PrepareReport();
       end
       else if FieldByName('draw_name').AsString='BIkE_TICKET' then
       begin
   frxCODOrdersReport.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\WebTicketPdf\BikeTicketPdf.fr3');
       end;
      Next;
    end;
    end;
   Screen.Cursor := crDefault;  // Or you can restore a saved cursor.
   frxCODOrdersReport.ShowReport();
```

But above code generates and  this prints or generates only first car ticket pdf only .

Comment: What do you get with : `if FieldByName('draw_name').AsString='BIKE_TICKET' then` instead of `if FieldByName('draw_name').AsString='BIkE_TICKET' then`  :: ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var IsFirst: Boolean;
with  frxCODOrdersDBDataset.DataSet do
begin
  First;
  IsFirst := True;
  while not Eof do
   begin     
      if FieldByName('draw_name').AsString='CAR_TICKET' then
       begin
        frxCODOrdersReport.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\WebTicketPdf\CarTicketPdf.fr3');
        frxCODOrdersReport.PrepareReport(IsFirst);
       end
   else if FieldByName('draw_name').AsString='BIkE_TICKET' then
     begin
       frxCODOrdersReport.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\WebTicketPdf\BikeTicketPdf.fr3');
       frxCODOrdersReport.PrepareReport(IsFirst);
     end;
    if IsFirst then IsFirst := False; 
    Next;
  end;
end;
Screen.Cursor := crDefault;  // Or you can restore a saved cursor.
frxCODOrdersReport.ShowPreparedReport();
```

Comment: I want the layout of the report to change according to my dataset value . I tried the above  it does not help ,What my intentions is that I want to show a text object when car ticket comes and when bike ticket comes instead of Text object I want to show  image object in the report layout

Comment: Attach your CarTicketPdf.fr3 and BikeTicketPdf.fr3, prepared report (fp3) and a sample what you want to get. Better to create a small demo project based on standart Delphi's components and local database like MS Access mdb